# Overleaf does not recognize math environments in parts of the document

Tags: math-mode, environments, overleaf

In some parts of my document math environments, such as "align", are not recognized, e.g. there is no arrow on the left to hide it, there is no automatic indent, and the theme colors are not applied properly. The same happens with "subsection", "section", etc. However, in other parts of the document the environments work.

What could be the reason and how do I fix this?

I am using pdfLaTeX compiler.

Here is an example of how it looks in the editor:

[image: First two environments are not recognized correctly]

Comment: If the document compiles correctly (so there's no LaTeX-relatd problem) and it's only an Overleaf bug, you should probably post that as a bug report to them. They seem to be quite reactive.

Comment: Note in general that syntax highlighting can fail in many ways so this is not unusual. As it is OverLeaf do remember to **not** ignore compilation errors.

Comment: Overleaf-specific questions should be posted to Overleaf's HelpDesk. Their LaTeX support staff are top-notch.

Comment: @Miyase thank you, I'll try that!

Comment: @daleif thank you, apart from the syntax highlighting there're no compilation errors

Comment: @Mico thanks, I'll try posting it there!